# How to change DNS servers for all NICS that contain specific ConnectionSpecificSuffix?

Tags: powershell

I can currently change DNS servers for all NICS on a list of computers.

```
$computer = gc C:\computerlist.txt

$NICs = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $computer | where { $_.IPEnabled -eq "TRUE"}

ForEach($NIC in $NICs) {
    $DNSServers = "10.1.140.3", "10.1.140.4"  # CHANGE THIS TO THE IP YOU WANT TO USE
    $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNSServers)
    $NIC.SetDynamicDNSRegistration(“TRUE”)
}
```

How do I only change DNS servers for NICs that are connected to a certain domain name?  Some computers may have more than one NIC and I only want to change DNS settings for NICS connected to "mytestdomain.local".

From reading PowerShell examples, it looks like the ConnectionSpecificSuffix shows the domain name.  (-ConnectionSpecificSuffix "mytestdomain.local")

Is there a way to edit my script and only change DNS settings for NICs that contain the suffix "mytestdomain.local"?

This doesn't :

```
$computer = gc C:\computerlist.txt

$NICs = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $computer | where { $_.IPEnabled -eq "TRUE" -and $_.ConnectionSpecificSuffix -eq "mytestdomain.local"}

ForEach($NIC in $NICs) {
    $DNSServers = "10.1.140.3", "10.1.140.4"  # CHANGE THIS TO THE IP YOU WANT TO USE
    $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNSServers)
    $NIC.SetDynamicDNSRegistration(“TRUE”)
}
```

Comment: Not comfortable with working on WMI objects but this post might help you Kade: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1034fb8e-b356-429e-9572-2f6260fb4a15/powershell-add-dns-domain-suffix-search-order?forum=ITCG

Comment: @KadeWilliams Did either of the answers [solve or help with your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration) instances do not have a `ConnectionSpecificSuffix` member.  They do, however, have `DNSDomain` and `DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder` properties.

Thus, I think what you're looking for is this...

```
$NICs = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $computer `
    | where { $_.IPEnabled -eq "TRUE" -and $_.DNSDomain -eq "mytestdomain.local" }
```

Alternatively, if you want to test if the target domain is among any of the search suffixes, regardless of order, then you'd do this...

```
$NICs = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $computer `
    | where { $_.IPEnabled -eq "TRUE" -and $_.DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder -contains "mytestdomain.local" }
```

By the way, this is untested but if your Windows version is new enough you could use the [`dnsclient` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/dnsclient/) to simplify your code to something like this...

```
Get-DnsClient -ConnectionSpecificSuffix 'mytestdomain.local' `
    | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses '10.1.140.3', '10.1.140.4'
```

It looks like calling [`Set-DnsClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/dnsclient/set-dnsclient) with the `-RegisterThisConnectionsAddress` parameter *might* do the same thing as calling [`SetDynamicDNSRegistration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/setdynamicdnsregistration-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration).

Answer (score 1):

There are pre-built scripts to get you to where you are trying to go. Teak them as needed. For example:

> [Set-DNSServerSearchOrder](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-DNSServerSearchOrder-67617b18)
>
> At times it is necessary to set the DNS Server Search Order on a
>   machine that is not receiving it's IP from DHCP.  This function will
>   allow you to do just that.  To verify the current setup of the DNS
>   Server Search Order, you can run the following Get-WmiObject command
>   and select
>
> Download: Set-DNSServerSearchOrder.ps1

```
# Validate DNS Search order
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName "Server01" -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE" | Select PSComputerName,DNSServerSearchOrder

# or using the DNS cmdlets to first collect the info
(DnsClientGlobalSetting).SuffixSearchList -match $env:USERDNSDOMAIN
Get-DnsClientServerAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Select *
(Get-DnsClientServerAddress -AddressFamily IPv4).ServerAddresses

# Modify DNS search order
function Set-DNSServerSearchOrder 
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        $ComputerName=$Env:ComputerName,
        [String[]]$DNSServers = @("10.10.10.1","10.10.10.2")
    )

    $getWmiObjectSplat = @{
        Filter = "IPEnabled=TRUE"
        ComputerName = $ComputerName
        Class = 'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration'
    }
    $NICs = Get-WmiObject @getWmiObjectSplat

    foreach($NIC in $NICs) 
    {
        $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNSServers) | 
        out-null
    }
}
```

Looking at / modifying the info using CIM instead. Leverage this...

```
$nics = [wmiclass]'win32_Networkadapterconfiguration'
[wmiclass]'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration'
$nics.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSSuffixSearchOrder")
$nics | select -ExpandProperty Properties
DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder
DNSServerSearchOrder


$cimClass = Get-CimClass win32_Networkadapterconfiguration
$cimClass.CimClassMethods
$cimClass.CimClassMethods["SetDNSSuffixSearchOrder"].Parameters
$cimClass.CimClassMethods["EnableDNS"].Parameters
$cimClass.CimClassMethods["EnableDNS"].Qualifiers

Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Networkadapterconfiguration
```